# DevOps - Puppet class not picking YAML variables values

Tags: yaml, puppet, devops, hiera

I have an issue on a Puppet module I'm creating. This module is not retrieving the variables value included into my YAML file.

The problem seems to come from that it's not reading the params.pp file in any case...

They are located in the right directories, matching what's in the variable name.

May you please have any idea ?

**My class** :

```
class bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport (
    $temp_path            = undef,
    $rejects_path         = undef,
    $logs_path            = undef,
    $done_path            = undef,
    $app_name             = undef,
    $app_version          = undef,
    $pkg_prefix           = undef,
    $archiver             = undef,
    $pkg_repos            = undef,
    $interface_input_path = undef,
  ) inherits bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params {

  $tmp_dir = "D:\\Temp\\${app_name}_${app_version}"
  $install_dir = "D:\\BSIC\\${pkg_prefix}${app_version}"
  $pkg = "${pkg_repos}\\CoreLibScripts\\${app_name}_${app_version}.zip"
  $inner_zip = "$tmp_dir\\${app_name}.zip"
  $output_inner_zip = "$tmp_dir\\Cab"

  bluesky::resources::extract { "Extract ${app_name}":
  pkg      => $pkg,
  archiver => $archiver,
  output   => $tmp_dir,
  }

  -> bluesky::resources::extract { "Extract InnerZIP ${app_name}":
  pkg      => $inner_zip,
  archiver => $archiver,
  output   => $output_inner_zip,
  }

  -> bluesky::resources::copydir { "Copy ${app_name}":
  source => $output_inner_zip,
  target => $install_dir,
  }

  -> class {'bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::configtemplates':
    install_dir => $install_dir
    }

  -> file {["D:\Interface","D:\Interface\OfferImport","D:\BSIC_DATA\OfferImport"]:
    ensure => directory
  }

  -> file {["${interface_input_path}",
         "${temp_path}",
         "${rejects_path}",
         "${logs_path}",
         "${done_path}",]:
    ensure => directory
  }

}
```

**My Params.pp :**

```
class bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params (

  String $interface_input_path         = undef,
  String $temp_path                    = undef,
  String $rejects_path                 = undef,
  String $logs_path                    = undef,
  String $done_path                    = undef,

  String $output_path                  = undef,
  String $om_servername                = undef,
  String $om_dbname                    = undef,
  String $om_login                     = undef,
  String $om_pwd                       = undef,
  String $name_cfg_ptnametopitype      = undef,
  String $name_cfg_pttors              = undef,
  String $name_cfg_suppponametotype    = undef,
  String $mn_schema_file               = undef,
  String $name_pivot_tmp               = undef,
  String $name_rejects_nopitype        = undef,
  String $name_rejects_norstype        = undef,
  String $name_rejects_piwithoutrs     = undef,
  String $name_rejects_powithoutpi     = undef,
  String $name_rejects_rswithoutre     = undef,
  String $name_warning_productoffering = undef,
  String $mn_helper_dll                = undef,

  String $archiver                     = lookup('bluesky::params::global::archiver'),
  String $pkg_repos                    = lookup('bluesky::params::global::pkg_repos'),

) inherits bluesky::resources::webapp::params {
}
```

**My ConfigTemplates.pp :**

```
class bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::configtemplates(
#  $title       = undef,
  $install_dir = undef,
)  inherits bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params {


  file { "${title} Parameters.ini":
      ensure  => 'file',
      path    => "${install_dir}\\Config\\Parameters.ini",
      content => template('bluesky/offerimport/config/Parameters.ini.erb'),
  }
}
```

**My YAML**

```
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::app_name:                                                                       OfferImport
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::pkg_prefix:                                                                     OfferImport\OfferImport_
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::signal_file:                                                                    BlueSky.BSIC.DA.UI.dll
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::configfolder:                                                                   config

    ##
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::interface_input_path:                                                   D:\Interface\OfferImport\Input
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::temp_path:                                                              D:\BSIC_DATA\OfferImport\Temp
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::rejects_path:                                                           D:\BSIC_DATA\OfferImport\Rejects
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::logs_path:                                                              D:\BSIC_DATA\OfferImport\Logs
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::done_path:                                                              D:\BSIC_DATA\OfferImport\Done
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::output_path:                                                            D:\BSIC_DATA\OfferImport\Output
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::om_servername:                                                          Servername
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::om_dbname:                                                              DatabaseName
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::om_login:                                                               DatabaseLogin
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::om_pwd:                                                                 DatabasePassword
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_cfg_ptnametopitype:                                                PTNameToPIType.csv
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_cfg_pttors:                                                        PTtoREandRS.csv
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_cfg_suppponametotype:                                              SuppPONameToType.csv
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::mn_schema_file:                                                         ProductCatalogtoBIver7.6.0.xsd
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_pivot_tmp:                                                         OFFER_IMPORT_PIVOT_TMP.csv
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_rejects_nopitype:                                                  OFFER_IMPORT_REJECTS_NoPIType.csv
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_rejects_norstype:                                                  OFFER_IMPORT_REJECTS_NoRSorREType.csv
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_rejects_piwithoutrs:                                               OFFER_IMPORT_REJECTS_PIWithoutRS.csv
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_rejects_powithoutpi:                                               OFFER_IMPORT_REJECTS_POWithoutPI.csv
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_rejects_rswithoutre:                                               OFFER_IMPORT_REJECTS_RSWithoutRE.csv
 bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::name_warning_productoffering                                          OFFER_IMPORT_ProductOffering_Warning.csv
    bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params::mn_helper_dll:                                                          BlueSky.BSIC.Com.MetraNet.dll
```

**My hiera.yaml** :

```
hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-node data"
    path: "nodes/%{trusted.certname}.yaml"
  - name: Common
    path: common.yaml
  - name: OfferImport
    path: offerimport.yaml

defaults:
  data_hash: yaml_data
  datadir: data
```

Thank you !

Comment: You are not supposed to use the deprecated `params.pp` pattern with the replacement Hiera 5 module data pattern. I do not know if they are compatible, but the `params.pp` is, at best, an extra useless file, and at worst, blocking your data lookups.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, there is no inherent incompatibility between the params class pattern and Hiera 5 module data, but it is not particularly useful to combine them.  If one does, the result follows from Puppet's ordinary scoping and data binding rules.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem seems to come from that it's not reading the params.pp file in any case...

This seems highly unlikely.  Class `bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport` inherits from class `bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params`, so Puppet will ensure that the latter is evaluated before the former.  This has been completely reliable since prehistoric Puppet.

You do seem to have incorrect expectations, however.  It is useless for the primary class to inherit from the params class because the params class declares no resources (I assume not indirectly, either), and ***the primary class does not use any of its variables***.  The primary class declares several parameters with the same names as parameters of the params class, but these are separate variables, and because they are local to the primary class, they hide the like-named ones in the parent class scope.

In the conventional params class pattern, one uses variables of the params class as default values for the primary class's parameters.  Indeed, the ability to do so is the only reason for involving class inheritance in this case.  Example:

```
class foo::params {
    $default_env = 'GUE'
    $default_greeting = 'Hello, Sailor!'
    $default_menace = 'grue'
}

class foo::messages (
  $env = $foo::params::default_env,
  $greeting = $foo::params::default_greeting,
  $menace = $foo::params::menace,
) inherits foo::params {
    notify { "In the ${env}, we say '${greeting}'  Try not to be eaten by a ${menace}.": }
}
```

One can then bind alternative values to the primary class's parameters by various means, including Hiera data.

It is atypical to set params-class data via data binding, because it's simpler to just bind data directly to the target class's parameters.  I can imagine scenarios for it, but yours doesn't appear to be one of them.  I suggest getting rid of the params class altogether, and modifying your Hiera data to bind values directly to (only) the target class.

Answer (score 0):

How is your file structure for this Params.pp (bluesky::components::webapp::offerimport::params) class?

it should be something like:

```
bluesky/
├── components
│   └── webapp
│       └── offerimport
│           └── manifests
│               └── params.pp
└── resources
    └── webapps
        └── manifests
            └── params.pp
```